# Parameterizing JPA Inbound Channel Adapters

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-data-jpa

I am currently developing an application based on the Spring Boot framework that is employing a JPA inbound channel adapter to retrieve data from a relational database.  I have a stored procedure named GetEmployee which needs to accept a value that varies based on the server instance on which the application is running.

I've looked at the Spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jpa.html#jpa-inbound-channel-adapter) on adapters, and it makes mention of a tag named **int-jpa:parameter** but that appears to only be utilized when the named-query attribute is utilized instead of the native-query attribute.

There is also a parameter-source attribute on the **int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter** tag, but I haven't found any good documentation on how to utilize it.

Is there a way to pass a parameter from a Spring bean to the native query?  Or is the better approach to use the named-query attribute?

Configuration XML:

```
    <int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter
        id="employeeAdapter"
        channel="employeeChannel"
        entity-manager-factory="entityManagerFactory"   
        entity-class="com.example.entities.Employee"
        native-query="EXEC emp.dbo.GetEmployee"
        expect-single-result="false"    
        delete-after-poll="false">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="10000">
            <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="DEFAULT"
              transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
        </int:poller>
    </int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that really work only if your query declare some parameters:

```
/**
 * Given a JPQL query, this method gets all parameters defined in this query and
 * use the {@link ParameterSource} to find their values and set them.
 *
 */
private void setParametersIfRequired(String queryString, ParameterSource source, Query query) {
    Set<Parameter<?>> parameters = query.getParameters();
```

Since your `EXEC` doesn't have any parameters in the procedure call, there is nothing to extract and apply for the supplied `int-jpa:parameter`s.

Consider to use `CALL emp.dbo.GetEmployee(?)` or `BEGIN emp.dbo.GetEmployee(?); END;`. Not sure which syntax will work for your RDBMS.

On the other hand, I'd take a look into Spring Integration [Stored Procedure support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html#stored-procedures) instead.